# Should we stick to a framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

I currently work with Zend Framework, but I also know about CodeIgniter and Kohana. I've just wonder that should I stick to a framework or depend on my purposes? Because I think I cannot master everything.

Comment: Just a note: ZF 2.0 will be out soon, and it introduces namespaces, so it will be somewhat incompatible with ZF 1.x. You may never need to upgrade your current apps, but you should be prepared that migrating from 1.x to 2.0 is not going to be an easy task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as your current framework does what you need it to do, stick with it. Switching frameworks takes some time and once you master the new framework, you will have a hard time to maintain older projects because your have already forgotten how that other framework worked.

Of course, if your current framework becomes desupported or the new framework is way better (as in: 10 times more productive), you might have to do the switch anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you already worked with Zend, stick with it. There are other Frameworks and (depending on your case) some might fit better than others. But if you dont have any major showstopper whithin Zend, then why switch? Dont switch because "you have read in some blog that said X".

Writing (and maintaining!) your own framework, will propably not be worth the effort. If you dont like the Zend Way try other Frameworks, but dont invent the 74.259's php web framework. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you can master Zend (or Symfony) then smaller frameworks are generally easier to pick up. I personally wouldn't use Zend for anything below a certain size/scope - things like Fat3 or Fuel are ideal for brochure sites, whereas CI and Kohana are intended for mid-scale sites like blogs. I would also recommend taking a look at [YAF](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.yaf.php), an MVC extension for PHP - it's got virtually no docs at the moment but it'll run significantly faster than a script based framework.

As an aside, I think there's a lot of value in writing your own framework (once you've used a couple), purely for academic purposes to give you a greater depth of understanding of MVC. But please don't release it...